# Interactive terminal emulation in JSF application

Tags: java, ssh, applet, jnlp, terminal-emulator

We are developing (basically data-mining) web application backed by JSF(Primefaces)/Spring/Hibernate. For next step, we have to create some sort of terminal emulation so the web application can SSH user to requested host.

Purpose of this question is to **find out right technology for our requirement**. Currently I am doing proof of concepts with java applets and jnlp, but don't understand them deep enough to see their limitation/possibilities in advance.

**Use case:** (simplified from the project specification):

Let's assume we do the emulation in java applet.
Imagine simple web page with p:selectOne menu (*hostMenu*), p:dataTable (*scriptTable*) and our applet. HostMenu items are backed by object that contains server URL, login and password. Selection change trigger event that will copy the data to applet and make the SSH connection.

Now in the scriptTable, there will be simple, predefined script defined by user. Think of the script as something really simple (such as *ls -l* on linux machine). Doubleclick event on the table will execute the script in the applet's ssh session.

**Some other requirements and contract limitations**

- ssh connection **must** be done on client computer (not on server)
- the emulation must be fully interactive (especially, on linux
  machines, TAB key autocompletes)
- on the web page, AJAX request does not reset the applet (it stays
  connected to the machine before the request)

Any response is appretiated. So are other technologies than applets/jnlp. For example, if you know possiblities hot to intercact from JSF with external emulator (Putty, linux console) we can use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think we have figured out at last using JCraft's [JCterm](http://www.jcraft.com/jcterm/). It required some changes to code, but it appears to work well (so far ;))

Answer (score 0):

For the frontend, check out Primefaces terminal component:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/terminalHome.jsf